# How to lay out my sections without using a table

Tags: html, css

I can force this layout with a table, but I think the best practice may be some display/float settings in CSS. I have a header and menu section that are working as desired. Below them are top, middle, and bottom sections that are wrapping ugly. The top section should have an image followed by a block of text. The middle section should have 3 equal blocks of text. The bottom (footer) should have 1 equal block of text. Is there a clean way to do this without stuffing it into a table? Here's what I'm doing so far and as I say it's ugly:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span class="HeaderTitle">My header info</span>
    </header>
    <nav>
 <!-- the menu is working fine -->
    </nav>
    <main>
        <style>
        .MyArticle
        {
            width: 30%; 
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 8px;
        }
        </style>
 <div class="jumbotron">
     <img src="/Images/Photo.jpg" style="border:solid 1px black; margin-right: 14px;" height="180px" align="left">
     <p class="lead">Some text</p>
 </div>
 <br/>

 <section id="MiddleSection">
     <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Current News</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
     <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Something</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
     <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Something</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
 </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <p>&copy; 2016 - Steve Gaines</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you draw out what it's supposed to look like? Or provide the table version, for us to compare? To start with, the `style` block should be inside `head`, and it's best to say `<style type="text/css">`. You can remove the `div` in the `footer`, and the footer <br/> can be replaced with top padding on the footer, and the <hr/> can be replaced with a top border

Comment: To your general question, yes, this is exactly the sort of thing CSS is used for :) People will probably give me a hard time for recommending W3 Schools, but if you're interested in learning this stuff I'd check out their CSS Tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. You just need to clear your floats, basically. Here's some reading on CSS Floats:

- [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)
- [CSS Floats 101](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101)
- [Mysteries of the Float Property](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jumbotron img {
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-right: 14px;
}
#MiddleSection {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.MyArticle {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
}
footer {
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <span class="HeaderTitle">My header info</span>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="/Images/Photo.jpg" height="180px" align="left">
        <p class="lead">Some text</p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <section id="MiddleSection">
        <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Current News</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
        <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Something</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
        <span class="MyArticle">
         <h2>Something</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
     </span>
    </section>
</main>
<footer>
    <div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <p>&copy; 2016 - Steve Gaines</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Though most people don't usually make content on their websites full-width (expand the Snippet to full screen to see what I mean).

Another way that's better/simpler for modern browsers is to use the Flexbox method (not really an option if you have to support IE8 or IE9, etc.).